# XPATH: select subset of xml file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

In my case, I have:

```
<booklist>
  <book id="1">
  </book>

  <book id="2">
  </book>

  <book id="3">
  </book>

  ......

</booklist>
```

How can i just return:

```
<booklist>
  <book id="1">
  </book>
</booklist>
```

if I use `/booklist/book[@id=1]`, I can only get

```
<book id="1">
</book>
```

But I also need the document element.
Thanks

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than selecting the element that you ***do want***, try *excluding* the elements that ***you don't want***.

**If you are just using XPATH**, this will select all of the elements except for the `book` elements who's `@id` is not equal to 1 (i.e. `<booklist><book id="1" /></booklist>`).

```
//*[not(self::book[@id!='1'])]
```

**If you want an XSLT solution**, this stylesheet has an empty template that matches all of the `<book>` elements that do not have `@id="1"`, which prevents them from being copied into the output.

Everything else (document node `<booklist>` and `<book id="1">`) will match the identity template, which copies forward.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!--Empty template to prevent book elements
        that do not have @id="1" from being
        copied into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="book[@id!='1']" />

    <!--identity template to copy all nodes and attributes to output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am facing a problem in xpath transformation in xml signatures in java. The xpath tranformation does not seem to take place. Can you please have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698287/xpath-transformation-not-working-in-java

Answer (score 3):

> How can i just return:
>
> ```
> < booklist >
> < book id=1 >
> < /book >
> < /booklist >
> ```

**XPath is a query language. Evaluating an XPath expression cannot change the structure of the XML document.**

This is why the answer is: *No, with XPath this is not possible*!

Whenever you want to *transform*  an XML document (which is exactly the case here), the probably best solution is to use XSLT -- a language which was designed especially for processing and transforming tree-structured data.

**Here is a very simple XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="book[not(@id=1)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML file, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<booklist>
   <book id="1"/>
</booklist>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you try to select a sub-element, only this will be returned.